# How to forward port to shared wired connection?

Tags: networking, network-manager, iptables

I connect to my wireless network through NetworkManager. In addition I have another computer connected to the first one through ethernet. I'm using NetworkManager to share the wireless connection of the first computer to the second one. Here's a diagram:

```
                Internet
                    |
                Wireless router (internal ip: 10.0.1.1)
                    |
                (Wifi)
                    |
Computer 1:     wlan0         eth0
                10.0.1.3      10.42.0.1
                                |
Computer 2:                   eth0
                            10.42.0.48
```

This setup works; Computer 2 has internet access. Additionally I can VNC or RDP from Computer 1 to 2.

Here's iptables rules after the wired connection is shared by NetworkManager:

```
$ sudo iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.42.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now I want to do some port forwarding so I can access the second computer from the wifi network (10.0.1.*), for example VNC (port 5900).

How can I do this??

Thanks!

Comment: Same as http://superuser.com/q/145188/78546